# Modification todate dimension in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need a suggestion around one of the columns that I'm creating in the Date dimension in SQL Server, basically rolling weeks..

I have a table `dimDate` in my datawarehouse.

I want to create a column in the `dimdate` table which will have week number in any year and each week should have 7 days.

For eg: In year 2015 there are 53 weeks but the 53rd week has only 5 days (because the week starts on Sunday in SQL Server I guess).

I want to include 2 more days from 2016 (1st and 2nd Jan in 2016) to complete the 53rd week with 7 days and also the the 1st week in 2016 should start on 3rd of Jan 2016, so on and so forth.

If there are any suggestions that will be great to start with.

Comment: You've almost answered your own question: "create a column in the dimdate which will have Week number in any year". Have you done that? Once you have you just write the correct update statement

Comment: I have the column weekofyear but that only gives 5 days to the 53rd week,I'm thinking of a proper update script not sure what it could be.

Comment: is this something that the business decides manually beforehand, or is there a hard and fast rule here? Whats the rule - is it that every week has 7 days, even if that extends into the next year? Is there any situation where it shouldn't? i.e. if is week 53 only has one day? To write the script you need clear rules. The first part of the script is identifying the last week number in every year - start with a select that does that.

Comment: Yip, the business should have decided before hand ,unfortunately not in this case and you are right the rule is every week must have 7 days even if it extends into the next year and the first week of the next year should again be starting with 1. If week 53 has 1 day then it must take in the first 6 days of the next year so basically next year has first week starting from 7th.

Comment: If it's an automated rule (not a manual business rule) then by all means proceed with a script. Assuming you already have a partially populated week number, the starting point is finding the last week in every year and counting how many days it has: `select year, max(weeknumber) wn from dimdate group by year`

Comment: I had the same plan to start with but haven't achieved what I aimed for so spinning my head around.

Comment: I'll post an answer but I need to make a number of assumptions

Comment: " and also the the 1st week in 2016 should start on 3rd of Jan 2016, so on and so forth." -  I wouldn't do that. Very confusing for end users....

Comment: Can't wait for the metric calendar. What will I do with all my spare time

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have weeks populated (but not extended into the next year), and making some assumptions about columns names

This query finds the last week in a year (which would almost always always be 53 but don't count on it:) and the date that it ends on

```
SELECT YearNo, MAX(Week) As Week, MAX(DateKey) As DateKey 
FROM dimDate
GROUP BY YearNo
```

This query finds all weeks that are shorter than 7 days, and how many extra days are required to make them 7 days.

```
SELECT 
YearNo, 
Week, 
7-COUNT(DISTINCT DateKey) As ExtraDaysRequired
FROM dimDate
GROUP BY YearNo, Week
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DateKey) < 7
```

This might *always* be the last week of the year but lets not make assumptions.

Lets combine these to find all final weeks that have less than 7 days, as well as add the number of days required:

```
SELECT 
Under7Days.YearNo, Under7Days.Week, Under7Days.ExtraDaysRequired,
FinalWeeks.DateKey StartDate, 
DATEADD(d,Under7Days.ExtraDaysRequired,FinalWeeks.DateKey) EndDate
FROM
(
SELECT YearNo, MAX(Week) As Week, MAX(DateKey) As DateKey 
FROM dimDate
GROUP BY YearNo
) As FinalWeeks
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT YearNo, Week, 7-COUNT(DISTINCT DateKey) As ExtraDaysRequired
FROM dimDate
GROUP BY YearNo, Week
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DateKey) < 7
) As Under7Days
ON  FinalWeeks.Week = Under7Days.Week
AND FinalWeeks.YearNo = Under7Days.YearNo
```

So we have a query that identifies the start date and end date and week number that it needs to be updated to. So now we run an update:

```
UPDATE TGT
SET Week = SRC.Week
FROM dimDate TGT
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
Under7Days.YearNo, Under7Days.Week, Under7Days.ExtraDaysRequired,
FinalWeeks.DateKey StartDate, 
DATEADD(d,Under7Days.ExtraDaysRequired,FinalWeeks.DateKey) EndDate
FROM
(
SELECT YearNo, MAX(Week) As Week, MAX(DateKey) As DateKey 
FROM dimDate
GROUP BY YearNo
) As FinalWeeks
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT YearNo, Week, 7-COUNT(DISTINCT DateKey) As ExtraDaysRequired
FROM dimDate
GROUP BY YearNo, Week
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DateKey) < 7
) As Under7Days
ON  FinalWeeks.Week = Under7Days.Week
AND FinalWeeks.YearNo = Under7Days.YearNo
) SRC
ON TGT.DateID BETWEEN SRC.StartDate AND SRC.EndDate
```

Looks complicated? There's half a dozen ways to write the same thing but this approach is step-by-step. You could probably write a windowing function to do the same thing but I leave that as an exercise for someone else.

Comment: I had another column in my dimension table using that I got the same solution which you have provided.Your solution is an amazing work , but there is only one issue here after the update statement 53rd week seems to have 7 days but after that the 1st week of the next year starts with week no 2 and I have the same issue with my solution. I checked my solution its almost same as yours but in more number of steps , but any idea how we can resolve the issue around missing 1st week from the updated dimdate? Update seems to update the 1st week and that is why the 1st week in the next year is lost.

Comment: So basically whatever you're using to get the week number (datepart I guess) has already worked it out for you - week 1 almost always needs to be set the the last week of the prior year? So his could be done differently. Just subtract 1 from all weeks then set week 0 to the prior week.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Probably not able to understand your fix but all I'm intending to say is whenever the 53rd week does not end on saturday it misses the first week and week number 1 =2.Still a bug.

Comment: If you look at your existing data _before_ you apply any scripts do you notice that week 1 is always the extra days that you need to add on (unless week 1 = 7 days)? This would be a simpler approach. (I'm assuming that you already populated week with something)